# Run java jar file and path to file it use. (Windows 7 and windows 2008 server)

Tags: java, windows, jar, path

I developed a small java application and export it to jar file (form eclipse). In this application I used xml file name to read input data from:

```
private static final String INPUT_FILE_NAME = "./tasks.xml";

............

    //read input tasks queue
    XMLDecoder decoder = null;
    try {
        decoder = new XMLDecoder(new BufferedInputStream(
                new FileInputStream(INPUT_FILE_NAME)));
        searchTasksQueue = (BlockingQueue<SearchTask>) decoder.readObject();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (decoder != null) {
            decoder.close();
        }
    }
```

When I run jar file I put tasks file within same folder with jar. 
Everything works right under windows 7. Though when I do the same under windows 2008 server I get:

```
C:\Users\Administrator>java -jar c:\scraper\scraper.jar
java.io.FileNotFoundException: .\tasks.xml (The system cannot find the file spec
ified)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at bmw.scraper.Starter.main(Starter.java:40)
```

Where is mistake? What to check to run this under Windows 2008 server?

PS

- on my Win 7 java version "1.8.0_45"
- on win 2008 server java version "1.8.0_60" (run through RDP client)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your file is within your jar folder then use Classloader to load your file.

Like below

```
InputStream in = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(fileName);
```

instead of

```
decoder = new XMLDecoder(new BufferedInputStream(
                new FileInputStream(INPUT_FILE_NAME)));
```

you can use fileInputStream is your are loading file externally.

check if this solution works for you.

Comment: It works. Will do more tests after a while. Do you have any Ideas why mentioned in my post solution not work under win 2008 server, and work under windows 7?

Comment: Thats great. Please don't forget to accept the answer/voteup if this answer has helped you.Yea its very strange if it worked on win 7 then it should have worked on Win server too. But I did the same thing (as you mentioned in problem) on my win7 machine and I got above error, so not sure how come its working for you. But generally whenever you are loading files from jar you should use classloader.